# What is the location of newly created folders from Imagemanager in OpenCart 2 on server?

Tags: php, mysql, opencart

Guys I'm having a strange problem. I'm not able to find newly created folders from `Imagemanager` in `OpenCart2` on server?

*For instance:*

I create a folder say **`New`** in `Imagemanager` while uploading product in Opencart. Image gets uploaded in folder and I get the link as **`domain.com/catalog/New/image.jpg`**
but when I open `catalog` folder on server, the **`New`** folder (and the image placed in it) is no where to be found ? How is this possible ? 
Does Opencart just create a virtual path instead of a real folder on server ? And if yes, then where do real images go on server if not in that folder ?

> **P.S** - I'm migrating from one server to another and when I upload
>   imported SQL file from 1st Opencart onto 2nd Opencart. I get tables in
>   the database but products does not show up on the front end part of
>   website? so please give me tips for migrating and for my query above

Thanks! Help appreciated :)

Comment: can you share the link?

Comment: have you checked in the `/image/catalog/` directory ?

Comment: @RahulChandrasekharan yes I've checked image/catalog also but no luck !

Comment: @VedPandya It is on local server as of now!

Comment: has the extension created any new table ?